# Override form.phtml in own module

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I want to override following file in my custom module:

> module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/shipping/method

What I did so far:

> magento/app/code/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_create_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>           
        <referenceBlock name="shipping_method">
            <referenceBlock name="form">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="shopmethtempindex" xsi:type="string">UV_Adressen::order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceBlock>

    </body>
</page>
```

Placed the template here:

> /var/www//magento/app/code//view/adminhtml/templates/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did the mistake

```
<referenceBlock name="form">
```

should be

```
<referenceBlock name="order_create_shipping_form">
```

also `<referenceBlock name="shipping_method">`  not need

that layout code should be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_create_shipping_form">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">UV_Adressen::order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```